# Typescript promise undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a function `fetchLyrics` which hits a service and subscribes to it and I currently use it as an Output event from a child component.

```
fetchLyrics($event) {
    console.log($event);
    this.apiService.get($event.artist, $event.song)
      .subscribe(
      (res) => {
        console.log(res);
        return res['lyrics'];
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
      }
    );
  }
```

I want to reuse the function in the same parent component in the callback for `getSuggestions`

```
getSuggestions(term) {
    this.apiService.suggest(term)
      .debounceTime(2000)
      .subscribe(
      (res) => {
        console.log(res);
        for (const item of res['data']) {
          const grab = this.fetchLyrics({
            artist: item.artist.name,
            song: item.title,
          });
          console.log(grab);
          item.playing = false;
        }
        this.songs = res['data'];
      },
      (err) => {
        this.songs = [];
        console.log(err);
      }
      );
```

But when I check my console log I see that `grab` returns `undefined` for every iteration of the data returned in `res['data']`

Comment: `fetchLyrics` does not return anything.

Comment: The question seems to be primarily Angular and RxJS, but there's no mention of it. There are even no promises.

Comment: Apologies yes it is an Angular and Observable question, 

Looking for advice on getting the returns to work

Answer (score 0):

Your fetchLyrics method does not return anything, actually it's subscribe on some service and once the data is back you return the response.

subscribe(Observable) does not working like that it will wait till the service return the data then it will execute the subscribe block, so once you call fetchLyrics method the observable is on async task and you will get undefined.

what you should is the following:

```
fetchLyrics($event) {
  console.log($event);
  return this.apiService.get($event.artist, $event.song)
    .map((res) => { 
      console.log(res);
      return res['lyrics'];
  });
}
```

And get suggestion as follows:

```
getSuggestions(term) {
  this.apiService.suggest(term)
    .debounceTime(2000)
    .subscribe(
    (res) => {
      console.log(res);
      for (const item of res['data']) {
        this.fetchLyrics({
          artist: item.artist.name,
          song: item.title,
        }).subscribe(
         (res) => {
           console.log(res);
           item.playing = false;
         },
         (err) => {
          console.log(err);
         }
      );
      this.songs = res['data'];
    },
    (err) => {
      this.songs = [];
      console.log(err);
    });
```